# Need advice for hosting a meteor project

Tags: meteor, hosting

I would like some advice for hosting a meteor.js project.

I found [this interesting post](http://joshowens.me/modulus-vs-heroku-vs-digital-ocean/), but I'd like to find the hosting service who will fit my need.

The application will be used by approximately 1200 users (I can't say how many at the same time, but not all of them for sure).
The application will be exported on smartphones (with notifications, generating a little more connexions I presume).

The application itself is pretty simple, a few authorized people can create posts, events, etc. Other users can comment, participate to events. So there is no need for big disk place (users won't be able to upload photos or videos).

For administration usage, I would like to be able to do database backup easily.

[Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/) seems to me a good choice (cheap, good rated), does the 10$/month offer will fit my need? In the post mentionned below, the guy use an external database provider (Compose.io) for his mongodb database. Is this really relevant?

Thank you for you help :)

Comment: Thank you Ethaan and tarmes for your answers. I have not decided yet but I think I'll try both Modulus and Digital Ocean for a month and do some benchmarks when the application will be a little more advanced.
Thank you again for your comments ;)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I use Digital Ocean with Compose.io for the database hosting.

I use Compose.io because hosting a database properly is complex and I'd rather leave that to the experts. You can choose to use Compose servers which are located in the same data center as Digital Ocean's, so that reduces the latency to a minimum and is another good reason to use DO.

We can't tell you how many users one server can handle since that depends so much on your application. With Digital Ocean it's trivial to add new Droplets when you need them, so scaling your application can be done as and when required.

Although setting up a meteor deployment seems overwhelming at first, using [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) it's really very easy to set up a server on DO. MeteorHacks new [Cluster](https://github.com/meteorhacks/cluster) solution also makes it trivial to scale it when necessary.

Comment: What is so "overwhelming" in setting up a meteor deployment? For my first tests with meteor.js I installed myself a full developpement (meteor + standalone mongodb) and production (node.js + mongodb + meteor builded project) environment on a personnal dedicated server and it was pretty clear to me (but I'm pretty used to server administration).

Or do you speak about beeing able to do a "meteor deploy" on a private server? (other than the meteor free hosting)

Comment: Well, if you're not used to server administration, then there's a lot to learn when to find yourself trying to set up a database, the server, the meteor installation, cloudflare, ssl. etc. Add to that the future scalability and the handling of multiple servers. Also, I develop on Mac - I had no knowledge of Linux and no experience installing and setting up stuff like node, nginx etc.  Compared to copying a bunch of PHP files to a hosting provider, it's overwhelming :)

Comment: Yeah I agree that hosting providers save you a lot of time and headaches ;)
I was just wondering if I was missing something in my meteor install, so apparently no.

Answer (score 1):

Actually im ussing [Modulus.io](http://modulus.io), give it a try the modulus team gave you 1 free month and the setup its pretty easy.

They have a [tutorial step-by-step](http://help.modulus.io/customer/portal/articles/1647770-using-meteor-with-modulus) to create-deploy and app into modulus.

They provide you a mongo database, the scalability its pretty fine(they use servos).

The reason i prefer Modulus.io its because they respect the path file on the deploys.